# Prototype scope bean in controller returns the same instance - Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, oop

I have a contoller which is defined as below:

```
@RestController
public class DemoController {

    @Autowired
    PrototypeBean proto;

    @Autowired
    SingletonBean single;

    @GetMapping("/test")
    public String test() {
        System.out.println(proto.hashCode() + " "+ single.hashCode());
        System.out.println(proto.getCounter());
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

And i have defined prototype bean as below:

```
@Component
@Scope(value= ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public class PrototypeBean {
    static int i = 0;

    public int getCounter() {
        return ++i;
    }
}
```

Everytime I hit http://localhost:8080/test
I get the same instance and the counter gets incremented everytime. 
How do I make sure that I get new instance everytime ?
Also I want to know why I am not getting new instance even though I have declared the scope of the bean as Prototype.

Answer (score 1):

You have declared `DemoController` as `@RestController`, so it's a bean with singleton scope. It means it's created once and `PrototypeBean` is also injected only once. That's why every request you have the same object.

To see how prototype works, you would have to inject the bean into other bean. This means, that having two `@Component`s, both autowiring `PrototypeBean`, `PrototypeBean`s instance would differ in both of them.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to achieve is done by using SCOPE_REQUEST (new instance for every http request).

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to get new instance of `PrototypeBean` each time the method `test()` is called, do `@Autowired` of `BeanFactory beanFactory`, remove the global class field of `PrototypeBean`, and inside the method `test()`, retrieve the `PrototypeBean` like:

```
PrototypeBean proto = beanFactory.getBean(PrototypeBean.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `static` variable is associated with class not with instance. Remove the static variable. Also add `@Lazy` annotation. 
Something like this

```
@RestController
public class DemoController {

    @Autowired
    @Lazy
    PrototypeBean proto;

    @Autowired
    SingletonBean single;

    @GetMapping("/test")
    public String test() {
        System.out.println(proto.hashCode() + " "+ single.hashCode());
        System.out.println(proto.getCounter());
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

```
@Component
@Scope(value= ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public class PrototypeBean {
    int i = 0;

    public int getCounter() {
        return ++i;
    }
}
```