# Does @Inject and java.security.Provider combination gives the instance with respect to its scope config?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, autowired, inject

In my Spring MVC app, I have a controller (a singleton) that has a `@Autowired` Service class.
Now I need to change the scope of the Service class because I changed it in the bean config to,

```
<bean id="managerService" class="com.company.xyz" scope="session" />
```

Since it was auto wired in a singleton class, the service class instance was always the same returned. What I actually needed was a session scope instance.
To solve that, I have implemented `@Inject` (which is likely similar to `@Autowired` by Spring) and Provider.

Old:

```
@RequestMapping("/home")
public class MyController {

    @Autowired
    ManagerService managerService;
```

New:

```
@RequestMapping("/home")
public class MyController {

    @Inject
    Provider<ManagerService> managerServiceProvider;
    
    ManagerService managerService = managerServiceProvider.get();
```

Here, I need to know, whether the `Provider.get()` returns the instance based on the bean scope configuration?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Ditch the new code and just leave `@Autowired ManagerService`. It will give you a proxy which will delegate to the session bound object. You are making things more complex then necessary. The `Provider<ManagerService>` doesn't add anything but complexity.

Comment: Then how to get an instance?

Comment: You don't need to, that is all handled for you by Spring. The only change you need to make is the `scope="session"` in your XML. Everything else can remain the same.

Comment: No, it does not work inside a controller, since it is auto wired. It gets instantiated at the time of application start up.

Comment: Thus, it always gives us a single instance.

Comment: Yes it does. As stated what you get injected is a proxy which delegates to the object in the scope. Each method call is transfered to a scoped object. If you inspect the instance closely you will see that it is a proxy. So it works (and what I just told you twice is also explained as is in the Spring Reference guide).

Comment: Are we on the same page? This is what I am trying to explain.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55036905/prototype-scope-bean-in-controller-returns-the-same-instance-spring-boot

Comment: Prototype scope is different from session scope. This question concerns session scope NOT prototype scope. For the web-scopes a proxy will get created, a prototype scoped bean is handled differently. So what you want works out-of-the-box for a session/request scoped bean.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to change anything apart from the configuration. Hence your XML change is all you need to do.

```
<bean id="managerService" class="com.company.xyz" scope="session" />
```

What now happens is that instead of an actual instance of the `ManagerService`, Spring will use some AOP/proxy magic and give you a proxy of the `ManagerService`. For each method called on the proxy, it will look in the scope it needs for an instance of `ManagerService`. It will either create a new instance or retrieve it, and call the actual method on that instance.